# Como baixar um arquivo compactado de uma URL e salvar no disco?

Tags: java, download, arquivo-zip

Fiz um programa em java para baixar um arquivo compactado (zip) de um servidor a partir de uma URL (no caso, estou usando localhost para testar), mas está dando o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry
>   compressed size (expected 5505 but got 7388 bytes).

A ideia do programa é fazer o download de um arquivo comprimido (zip) e salvá-lo no disco do PC (não descomprimir, apenas salvar).

Dentro do arquivo zipado coloquei dois arquivos txt e uma imagem bmp, nada muito grande, apenas para testar.

Creio que o erro não seja no arquivo zip, pois utilizei o winrar para comprimi-lo, desta forma, acho que o meu programa é que está errado, mas não consigo descobrir o erro. Segue o código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

    URL url = new URL("http://localhost/zipado.zip"); //conecta com localhost e busca o arquivo a ser baixado
    InputStream is = url.openStream();  // abre um fluxo de dados para baixar o arquivo
    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(is); // cria um fluxo para ler arquivos zipados
    File f = new File("C:/saida/zipado.zip"); // cria um arquivo de saida
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f); // abre um fluxo para gravar os dados no disco
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fout); // cria um fluxo para zipar dados
    while (true) {
        ZipEntry ze = zin.getNextEntry(); // recebe os "entrys" do arquivos baixado
        if(ze==null) // verifica se ja recebeu todos os "entrys"
            break;
        System.out.println("Unzipping " + ze.getName()); // apresenta os "entrys"
        zos.putNextEntry(ze); // posiciona o próximo entry
        for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {               
                zos.write(c);   // escreve os dados no arquivo               
        }
        zos.closeEntry(); // fecha o entry
   }
   zos.close(); // fecha para zipar dados
   fout.close(); // fecha para gravar no disco
   zin.close(); // fecha o fluxo de entrada
}
```

O erro ocorre quando termina de pegar todos os "entrys", no seguinte trecho:

`zos.closeEntry();`

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para resolver esse problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roger, se voce já está realizando o download do arquivo zipado voce não precisa utilizar a classe ZipEntry, basta apenas realizar o Download do arquivo e salvar em disco.
Segue um exemplo de código para download do arquivo e save no disco.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

    File arquivoDeSaida = new File("C://saida//zipado.zip");
    HttpURLConnection url = null;
    InputStream inStream = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

    try {

        // conecta ao local host para realizar o download do arquivo
        url = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://localhost/zipado.zip").openConnection(); 
        url.setDoInput(true); // configura a conexao para aceitar o recebimento de dados
        url.connect(); // efetiva a conexao ao localhost

        inStream = url.getInputStream();
        fileOutputStream  = new FileOutputStream(arquivoDeSaida); // abre um fluxo para gravar os dados no disco

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesLidos = 0;

        while ((bytesLidos = inStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesLidos);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (url != null)
            url.disconnect();
        if (inStream != null)
            inStream.close();
        if (fileOutputStream != null)
            fileOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Nesse caso estamos apenas realizando o download do arquivo e salvando o mesmo no disco.

Se fosse necessário baixar o arquivo e logo em seguida zipalo, bastaria realizar o download e depois utilizar o código para zipar.

Comment: Entendi. Então não necessita nenhum tratamento especial para baixar arquivos compactados?! Eu estava "zipando" o "zip"?
obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: Exato, como voce disse voce estava "zipando" um zip ao realizar o download e isso não é necessário.

O ideal é sempre fazer o download do arquivo por completo e depois fazer o que preferir com o arquivo.
Abraços :)

Answer (score -2):

o problema está na instância do objeto `ze`.
tenta assim:

```
ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(zin.getNextEntry().getName());
```

Comment: Infelizmente essa solução não funcionou. Agora retorna o erro de "NullPointerException".